# loopback where field is null

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

How can I query a field which is null? I get a a sql error

filter=[where][category_id][eq][null] results in

```
SELECT WHERE category_id'null' ORDER BY id
```

using latest version of loopback and loopback-connector-mysql

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` like

```
/model?filter[where][category_id][eq]=null
```

**As you see in loopback**

```
/medias?filter[where][keywords][inq]=foo&filter[where][keywords][inq]=bar
```

reference link : [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html)